# Magento Enterprise Cache Displaying Same Product Multiple Times in Related Products

Tags: magento-enterprise, full-page-cache

I am trying to figure out why a Magento Enterprise website is displaying the same item four times in the 'related item' section of the page.

CORRECT BEHAVIOR:
- After clearing caches, four *different items* are shown on the first page load (this is the correct behavior)

PROBLEM:
- Additional page loads show not just the same four items, but the *exact same item* repeated four times (see screenshot)
- The item which is repeated is always the *last item* that was displayed in the original page load. In other words if there are a,b,c,d related items shown on the first page load after a cache fush, it is 'd' that will be repeated four times on future page loads. d,d,d,d

[image: Same exact item repeated four times]

BACKGROUND:
- Page uses a custom theme.
- This problem only takes place when full page caching is turned on.
- If the page is returned to the 'default' theme, the problem no longer takes place, even with full page caching turned on
- To recap: the problem only occurs with the custom theme and full page caching turned on
- Magento Enterprise ver. 1.13.0.0

The related products portion of the page is inserted with the following code:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('relatedProducts', false) ?>`

I would be grateful for:
- A specific lead on what this issue may be
- Reliable ways to disable a specific cache related to this (in GUI? In code? In terminal?)
- Tests and steps I can take to narrow this down to code, db, or files.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that we had created a local version of the default ***related.phtml*** file which was being used as the template for the related items block. In this code there is this line within a loop:

`$itemBlock = $this->getChild('catalog.product.related.item')->setItem($_item)->setPosition($i);`

***Notice the $i variable near the end of the line.*** 
This variable was not being incremented elsewhere in the code. I added `$i = 0;` before the loop and `$i++;` in the appropriate location within the loop. With the $i variable now incrementing, the repeating item problem has been resolved.

Comment: Great to see this problem addressed as I haven't seen it on here before - but you could revise the answer to give more generic information that would be valuable for future visitors.